# How to automate a JS script to keeping repeating a instruction?

Tags: javascript, automation

My goal is to make a script click continuously on this two button without need to call it manually, my script have the ability to click on the button, but I don't know 
how to automate the action, what I'm trying to do is keeping clicking with no number limit of clicks.

## **The script I used to click on the button**

---

> ```
>     let buttonTags = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
> let followButton = "Follow";
> let unFollowButton = "Unfollow";
> let found;
>
> for (let i = 0; i < buttonTags.length; i++) {
>   if (buttonTags[i].textContent == followButton || unFollowButton) {
>     found = buttonTags[i];
>     break;
>   }
> }
>
> found.click()
> ```

---

### **This is the test, I used two divs intentionally.**

**HTML**

```
<div id="hidde">

            <button onclick="myFunction()">Follow</button>

        </div>


        <div id="hidden">

            <button onclick="myFunction()">Unfollow</button>

        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  body{
        display: flex;
    }
    div{
        border: #000 solid 1px;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    #hidden {
        display: none;            
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction() {
        let y = document.getElementById("hidde");
        let x = document.getElementById("hidden");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
            y.style.display = "none";
            } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
            y.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try using setInterval() function. Here is MDN documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically trigger a click with .click()

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp

But also your use case perfectly suits a Do/While loop :)